# Read entries from text file into a variable in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I hope someone can help me.  I am pretty new to PowerShell and can't really script it myself with the exception of looking at existing code and modifying it.

I have found a PowerShell script that reports file share permissions for a specific share and recurses through the subfolders returning their permissions as well.

My problem is I need to do this with a lot of shares so would like to be able to provide the script with a text file containing the share names.  I know I need to do a for each loop and read the names of the shares in a text file into an array but I don't know how to do this.  I guess it's pretty simple for someone with more experience.

This is the script i have used with single entry.

http://mywinsysadm.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/powershell-reporting-ntfs-permissions-of-windows-file-shares/

```
#Set variables
$path = Read-Host "Enter the path you wish to check"
$filename = Read-Host "Enter Output File Name"
$date = Get-Date

#Place Headers on out-put file
$list = "Permissions for directories in: $Path"
$list | format-table | Out-File "C:\scripts\$filename"
$datelist = "Report Run Time: $date"
$datelist | format-table | Out-File -append "C:\scripts\$filename"
$spacelist = " "
$spacelist | format-table | Out-File -append "C:\scripts\$filename"

#Populate Folders & Files Array
[Array] $files = Get-ChildItem -path $path -force -recurse

#Process data in array
ForEach ($file in [Array] $files)
{
#Convert Powershell Provider Folder Path to standard folder path
$PSPath = (Convert-Path $file.pspath)
$list = ("Path: $PSPath")
$list | format-table | Out-File -append "C:\scripts\$filename"

Get-Acl -path $PSPath | Format-List -property AccessToString | Out-File -append "C:\scripts\$filename"

} #end ForEach
```

Sorry for the noob question.  I plan to learn more when I have a bit more time but any help now would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a Google search for "powershell read file" and "powershell loops"? Those two topics will help you along.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a share name on each line within your text file can put all the shares into an array like this:

```
$path = "C:\ShareNames.txt"
$shareArray = gc $path
```

To access the first share you can use this syntax:

```
$shareArray[0]
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach.  You don't need to declare an empty array and sequentially add to it (which requires allocating a new array at every step, plus extra code).  Just do `$shareArray = gc $path`.  Done!

Comment: If there is only one line, the above solution won't create an array, but this will: `$shareArray = (Get-Content "C:\ShareNames.txt").Split([Environment]::NewLine)`